# Java Swing - Creating dynamic windows

Tags: java, swing

I use a window to get the files to read and then I pass them to a new window to process them. I turn the files into `Properties` objects and then i loop through them like this:

```
for(String key : propDef.stringPropertyNames()) {
          String value = propDef.getProperty(key);
          System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
        }
```

the loop actually works fine the problem is i need to create `JtextFields` and `Jbuttons` dynamically depending on the number of keys in the file. Can anyone explain me how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, but you need to learn basic Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just do panel.add(new JTextField()); within the for loop.
panel represents your container name, where the JTextField is going to be displayed.
Exactly the same approach for buttons or any other control.